# How can a jQuery plugin be reloaded/redrawn/updated to refresh its values?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, reload

I believe this is easy to accomplish but I can't find how to do it. Is it possible to reload a jQuery plugin without refreshing the entire page so it can refresh its values? I've read similar questions but they're targeted to specific plugins. I'd like to know if someone knows a "generic" way to accomplish this, so it can be used in many JQ plugins.

Anyway, more specifically, I'm asking this question to reload [jQuery File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/). I've got this:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#fileTree').fileTree({
        root: '/some/path/to/somewhere/',
        script: 'js/jqueryFileTree-1.01/connectors/jqueryFileTree.php',
        folderEvent: 'click',
        expandSpeed: 1000,
        collapseSpeed: 1000,
        multiFolder: false,
        loadMessage: 'Loading...'
        }, function(file) {
            relativePath=file.replace("/some/path","");
            aFunction(relativePath, file);
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="fileTree" class="fileTree"></div>
```

At a certain point, I've got AJAX+PHP code that let's me delete the selected file. This works well! BUT the file that has been deleted it's still showed in the file tree. If I add a `window.location.reload()` in my success event in that function, obviously the entire page it's reloaded and my tree shows the actual files in the folder as intended.

Question: *Is there a way to reload it without refreshing the entire page?*

Please note the author of this plugin has told me on Twitter:

> @metafaniel Problem is it's no longer used in any of our projects.
> It's an old, old script that needs an overhaul. via @abeautifulsite
>
> @metafaniel You'll have to add that yourself. As the plugin is very
> old, it doesn't have a complete API. via @abeautifulsite

I don't have more time to re-write my code with another plugin, I have to finish it this way.

Comment: Usually, you can just call the plugin again with the same parameters to reset/reload it.

Comment: Empty the parent `div` (`#fileTree`) and call the plugin again

Comment: Well, yeah OF COURSE Thanks to both. Yeah that's a way I did before but there must be other way... I've got the Javascript code in a JS file... Maybe theres some code to just run the .js code directly?? Do you know a way to do that? Thanks for your help =)

Comment: did you figure out a better way to do this?

Comment: @digitalWestie Sorry I haven't found a solution yet u.u mainly because I'm now in a new office and here they use `MooTools` instead of `JQuery` so I haven't researched about JQuery lately. If you found one solution, don't hesitate to post it as an answer here. THANKS!

Comment: I found out a way to do it with the plugin I was using. I think the answer is that it's dependent on the plugin you use. It's not something provided by jQuery itself. I.e. the plugin should provide a way to detach/re-attach its behaviour and/or it should handle changes to the document.

Comment: Probably you're right, maybe JQuery by itself can't "force" a plugin to reload if it hasn't a method to do so... Thanks =)

Comment: @js1568 just calling `$fileTree.empty();` didn't work for me; Additional line `$fileTree.data('fileTree', null);` did remaining cleaning job

Comment: @Blazemonger - "Usually, you can just call the plugin again" - Nope, doesn't do it for fileTree.

Comment: @js1568 - "Empty the parent div (#fileTree) and call the plugin again" Again, doesn't seem to work for fileTree. In fact, clearing the target div seems to break the code, preventing it from loading.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the OP is asking for a direct plugin command to do this, I'm afraid it may not exist. Here is my solution, which works pretty well. What you do is wrap your empty `<div id="jstree"></div>` in a parent div, something like this:

```
<div id="file-tree-holder">
    <div id="jstree" ></div>
</div>
```

Then, in your javascript, just before you instantiate your plugin, you clear the contents of the **parent div**, and then re-write the target div within the parent div, like so:

```
        $('#file-tree-holder').html('');
        $('#file-tree-holder').html('<div id="jstree" ></div>');
        $('#jstree').fileTree({
            script: '/ajax/file_tree2/' + path,
            multiFolder: true,
            expandSpeed: 250,
            collapseSpeed: 250,
            loadMessage: 'Loading...'
        });
```

...and it works pretty well.

Comment: Have been struggling for it for 3 days. Upvote done.